# Could type traits be restricted to not accept other type traits as arguments?

Tags: c++, type-traits, c++20, c++-concepts

Question may be weird so here is a brief motivational example:

```
#include <vector>
#include <type_traits>
template <typename T>
// workaround for gcc 8.3 where volatile int is not trivially copyable
using is_tc = std::is_trivially_copyable<std::remove_cv<T>>;
// static assert passes compile, oops
static_assert(is_tc<std::vector<int>>::value);
```

As you can see mistake is that I have passed the type trait itself to another type trait instead of passing `::type` or using `std::remove_cv_t`.

Obvious solution is for me to not make mistakes, but I wonder if is there a way C++ type traits could restrict their input types so that they do not accept other type_traits as arguments.
Now the hard thing is that there is a huge set of type traits in type_traits so IDK how would one go best about implementing this.

Note: I am not saying C++ should do this, I know it is a lot of work to prevent rare bugs, I am just trying to learn about more complicated concepts design where your restriction is not based on semantics of types(aka has ++ and *) but on the fact that types belong to a huge set of types(and that set includes the type you are restricting on).

Comment: The usual way to tag a set of type is.... another trait!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Concept: Is a TransformationTrait declared in the `std` namespace

> I wonder if is there a way C++ type traits could restrict their input types so that they do not accept other type_traits

Since metafunction traits are actually types themselves (which is kind of also the root of your problem), we can leverage this and construct a concept for `T` for whether Argument-Dependent Lookup (ADL) can find a *smaller select set* of STL-functions via ADL on an object of type `T` (in a non-evaluated context), where `T` may potentially be a metafunction trait; essentially an ADL-based (possibly brittle - see below) mechanism to query whether a given type `T` is defined in the `std` namespace or not, as opposed to the verbose approach of querying whether `T` is exactly one of numerous trait types defined in the `std` namespace.

If we combine this with the [*TransformationTrait* requirement](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/TransformationTrait):

> #### C++ named requirements: *TransformationTrait*
>
> A *TransformationTrait* is a class template that provides a transformation of its template type parameter.
>
> *Requirements*:
>
> - Takes one template type parameter (additional template parameters are optional and allowed)
> - The transformed type is a publicly accessible nested type named `type`

we can construct a common concept for a type `T` being a transformation trait in the `std` namespace. Note however that relying on ADL in this sense can be somewhat brittle, if for some reason a given project starts to declare functions which overloads function names from the STL. Expanding the *smaller select set of STL-functions* in the concept for possible ADL-lookup will make it harder to break from a non-`std`-implementor perspective.

E.g. defining a few concepts as follows:

```
namespace traits_concepts {

template <typename T>
concept FindsStlFunctionByAdlLookupOnT = requires(T t) {
  // Rely on std::as_const being found by ADL on t, i.e.
  // for t being an object of a type in namespace std.
  as_const(t);

  // If we are worried that a user may define an as_const
  // function in another (reachable/found by lookup)
  // namespace, expand the requirement with additional
  // STL functions (that can be found via ADL).
  move(t);
  // ...

  // Remember to add the appropriate includes.
};

template <typename T>
concept IsTransformationTrait = requires {
  // REQ: The transformed type is a publicly accessible
  // nested type named type.
  typename T::type;
};

template <typename T>
concept IsStlTransformationTrait =
    IsTransformationTrait<T> && FindsStlFunctionByAdlLookupOnT<T>;

template <typename T>
concept IsNotStlTransformationTrait = !IsStlTransformationTrait<T>;

}  // namespace traits_concepts
```

Applied as:

```
namespace not_std {

template <traits_concepts::IsNotStlTransformationTrait T>
struct NotAnStlTrait {
  using type = T;
};

struct Foo {};

};  // namespace not_std

// Is an STL transformation trait
static_assert(
    traits_concepts::IsStlTransformationTrait<std::remove_cv<const int>>);
// Is not an STL transformation trait.
static_assert(
    !traits_concepts::IsStlTransformationTrait<std::remove_cv_t<const int>>);
static_assert(
    !traits_concepts::IsStlTransformationTrait<not_std::NotAnStlTrait<int>>);
static_assert(!traits_concepts::IsStlTransformationTrait<not_std::Foo>);

int main() {}
```

And, for a custom trait added to `std` (assume for now that we are a compiler vendor; adding names to the `std` namespace is UB):

```
namespace std {

// Assume we are a compiler vendor.
// (Adding names to the std namespace is UB).
template <traits_concepts::IsNotStlTransformationTrait T>
struct custom_stl_trait {
  using type = T;
};

};  // namespace std

static_assert(
    traits_concepts::IsStlTransformationTrait<std::custom_stl_trait<int>>);
static_assert(!traits_concepts::IsStlTransformationTrait<
              std::custom_stl_trait<int>::type>);

int main() {}
```

[**DEMO**](https://godbolt.org/z/JRVvVE).

Comment: are you sure no containers/other types in std:: do not have ::type member?

Comment: @NoSenseEtAl The containers only have the more verbose typedefs (`value_type` and so on). Afaik, beyond the transformation traits (including `std::enable_if`), only `std::tuple_element` and `std::variant_alternative` have the `type` member typedef. These ”underlying variant type” accessors have similar semantics to the transformation traits, though, and it’s highly likely the underlying variant type (typedefed `type`) should ever only be used in a trait context.

Comment: @NoSenseEtAl Any other feedback on this? I don't see any other viable options short to the [trait-definition-invasive change proposed by Alex Guteniev](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62258020/4573247) or to explicitly annotate all traits for each given standard version.

Comment: This looks like the best solution to me, but I must warn you that I am definately not a C++20 expert, so me accepting this answer does not mean it is the best. It just looks like the best answer to me.

Comment: @NoSenseEtAl Imo any complexity of this question is not really C++20 techniques, but rather that all answers (including this one) relies of somewhat brittle techniques as to detect "`T` is a trait" and, extended, "`T` is an STL-trait" (existence of `type` typedef // composed concept of STL-named functions that shall all be found for a given type `T`, _hoping_ no user implements all those functions for a non-STL type, and so on). The proper solution, if this was a feature one would actually want, would probably be to write an evolution proposal for expanding STL-traits with some trait-notation.

Answer (score 4):

Well, assuming you always need a `::type` as argument where possible, here's a quick workaround:

```
template<class T> concept HasType = requires { typename T::type; };
template<class T> concept HasNoType = !HasType<T>;

template<HasNoType T> using remove_cv = std::remove_cv<T>;
template<HasNoType T> using remove_cv_t = typename remove_cv<T>::type;
```

Other than patching STL headers, or subclassing STL types (which is not always permitted), you cannot redefine what was predefined.

> your restriction is not based on semantics of types(aka has ++ and *) but on the fact that types belong to a huge set of types

Whatever goes, you'll need a predicate to specify this set (operator `∊S` for a given S). For instance `has ++` is as good a predicate as any other.

The predicate can be refined with more levels of indirections and some boilerplate, say

```
template<class T> struct not_a_type_trait =
        std::integral_constant<bool, HasNoType<T>> {};
template<class T> inline constexpr not_a_type_trait_v = not_a_type_trait<T>::value;
template<class T> concept NotATrait = not_a_type_trait_v<T>;

struct AnArg { using type = void; };
template<> struct not_a_type_trait<AnArg>: std::true_type {};
    // now can be an arg to remove_cv
```

Or, here in this particular case, you can simply blacklist all the STL's traits, but that would be a really huge predicate to be updated with each Standard revision.

Comment: problem is that some of my types might have ::type typedef, ie struct S {int x; int y; using type = int; };

Comment: I've complicated my answer. :)

Answer (score 1):

I think that it is possible if all traits would have check for other traits, like all traits are inherited from `_Trait`, and do st `is_base_of_v` on its template parameter:

```
template<class T>
struct remove_cv : private _Trait
{
    static_assert(!is_base_of_v<_Trait, T>, "Don't pass traits to traits");
    using type = T;
};
```

If you want warning instead of hard error, this is harder. Need to make `static_assert`  to evaluate as always `true`, but instantiating `[[deprecated]]` class for trait passed to trait.

---

Another simple solution would be to mark `[[deprecated]]` all traits that require `::type` or `::value`, deprecate them in favor of `_t` / `_v`. This is non-standard, but can be done under some preprocessor macro. or this deprecation can be made available by including a header that lists those deprecations.

Answer (score 0):

The usual way to tag a set of type is to use a trait ;-)

```
template <class T>
struct is_trait : std::false_type {};

template <class T>
struct is_trait <is_trait <T>> : std:: true_type {};

template <class T>
inline constexpr auto is_trait_v = is_trait:: value;
```